# How to redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My situation is the following visiting my website...

Typing in browser `http://example.com` it redirects to `http://www.example.com` (**with www. but insecure**), and this is my problem.

Instead, if I type in the browser `http://www.example.com` it redirect **correctly** to `https://www.example.com` (secure connection).

I need to redirect both the URLs `http://example.com` **and** `http://www.example.com` **always to** `https://www.example.com`.

How to reach this result?
Thanks a lot for your help.

My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit**: the solution is to force https redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your question contains several inconsistencies... your title states "to `https://website.com` not working" - don't you mean `www.website.com`? You state in the first example that you are typing `mysite.com` and then using `mywebsite.com` as the target? Do you really have 3 separate domains? Or are these just careless typos? (Please use `example.com` instead.) What is triggering the redirect in your second example (from `www.mywebsite.com` to `https://www.mywebsite.com`), or are you actually typing HTTPS in the first place and no redirect actually occurs?

Comment: (...and if the second example is from `http://www.mywebsite.com` then your first example should also redirect to `https://www.mywebsite.com`, so I assume you must be requesting HTTPS to begin with in your second example?)

Comment: Excuse me for confusion ant thanks for the first answer, I edited title and text to clarify.

Comment: (Use backticks to format URLs - to avoid auto-linking - and other inline code snippets.)

Comment: It doesn't look like your existing `.htaccess` code is doing anything? Are you sure `.htaccess` overrides are enabled and mod_rewrite is enabled? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? The rule you've posted always redirects to `HTTPS`, so in your first example `http://example.com` should be redirected to `https://www.example.com` by the rule you've posted. It looks like _something else_ is issuing that redirect? But if typing `http://www.example.com` redirects to `HTTPS` then why is the first example not redirected to `HTTPS` as well? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am not aware of the server configuration because the site resides on a hosting service. The problem is that customer service is not responding to me. If the .htaccess file is correct the redirection does not work, if you want I will provide the site address privately.

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper. Any error? Type some _nonsense_ at the top of the file - any error? Try a simple redirect. eg. `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [R,L]` - if you request `/foo`, are you redirected to `/bar`? And to clarify, you have no other directives in this `.htaccess` file? No other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: No errors removing the `<IfModule>` wrapper or add some nonsense at the top of file; the browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Tor with cache cleared) load the `http` not secure home page.
`RewriteRule ^page1.html$ /page2.html [R,L]` don't redirect. 
In this `.htaccess` file there's no other directives.
There's no other `.htaccess` files, the website is very simple written in html and css.
At this point I think it is a misconfiguration of the hosting server, and the only thing to do is to add a redirect meta tag in every html page. :(

Comment: The solution that work is to force https (from hosting customer care, finally). I edited the main post including the code.